# Why .txt file in <iframe> is getting downloaded instead of displayed?

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, download, struts2

I am using an `<iframe>` to display a text file:

```
<div class="document-view">
    <img src="img/302.GIF" />
</div> 

$(window).load(function () {
    <s:if test="extention.equalsIgnoreCase('txt')">
      element = '<iframe class="iframe" src="/dmsrepo/<s:property value="docLocation"/>" />';
    </s:if>

    $('.document-view').html(element);
});
```

When I inspect element in the browser I can see the file location.

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="/dmsrepo/Legal Doc Type/LegalDocType_123456789_1.0.txt" />
```

But the text file is getting downloaded in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

How to resolve this issue?

---

**EDIT**: you can reproduce the behavior in the following fiddle, that strangely affects only Firefox, for every page load after the first one.

> Simply [open the page](http://jsfiddle.net/0wxw423d/), then press <kbd>Run</kbd>.

Note: it affects also the first load if Firebug Net module is activated.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Nope..still file getting downloaded..

Comment: @AndreaLigios You are right..It is downloaded when i refresh page in firefox.But no issues in IE or chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the issue with the file. it is not formatted as html. because it has some special unicode (eg) characters at end of file read. if text response has special character like that. it failed to parse response as html embedded in iframe.

you can check this example :

```html
<iframe src='http://humanstxt.org/humans.txt' /> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 5):

because browser understands only html. Change your file extension to .html

or use server side language like php and using file_get_contents() function, you can display text file to browser.

Comment: Then why does it work on Chrome, IE, etc ? And also on Firefox the first time ?

Comment: Well, +1 because of the last link. @prince try renaming the .txt file to .html and see if it works in Firefox too

Comment: I tried changing the extension but the html view doesn't contain any line break.So it wont maintain the structure of the text file.So I think I should make it as an html file with </br> in business logic.

Answer (score 2):

to display file add below line(s) in .htaccess

```
AddType text/plain .txt
AddType text/plain .log
```

This is signal Firefox that you don't have to download the file instead view file as plain text.This technique can be applied to all the files that you need to view instead off download.

Answer (score 1):

The [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header could be the culprit. If set to `attachment; filename="..."` then the file will download. If set to `inline` then it can displayed in the Web page.

If you are serving these files from Amazon S3, you can add Metadata to the file with the `Key=Content-Disposition` and the `Value=inline`.

*Note: the default value is typically `inline`.*