# why is text file in iframe downloaded instead of opening

Tags: html, iframe

seen several questions for the same, but no working answers.

On my raspberry, I have a simple HTML page, with several iframes calling text files showing various aspects of system health.

Some of them display, some of them download... the code is identical for each, the files are simple text/log files generated by the raspberry.... I have no idea why the behaviour differs

I copied the content of one file to the other, one iframe displays, the other iframe downloads

This one is visible in the browser

```
<iframe style="background-color:#8FBC8F" src="data/uptime_log.txt" width="1000" height="200" frameborder="5" scrolling="yes" ></iframe>
```

This one always downloads

```
<iframe style="background-color:#8FBC8F" src="data/bad_read.txt" width="1000" height="200" frameborder="5" scrolling="yes" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Could you include the other questions/answers you tried and how/why they didn't work for you?

Comment: most of the suggestions are generic, so do not explain why this works for one statement, not the other.  the only one I could see that was specific suggested adding a 'type' attribute, but that didn't seem to do anything... again, doesn't explain the differing behaviour.

Comment: alternative is, I don't care what method is used to show the text... is there another way to display the content of a text file within a html view?

Comment: Related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860875/why-txt-file-in-iframe-is-getting-downloaded-instead-of-displayed#42664445).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to load a file and retrieve its contents. I like using `async await fetch` since it's easier to use.

```
async function loadFile(src) {
  var text = await (await fetch(src)).text()
  document.getElementById("displayText").innerText = text;
}
```

Here is also a way using `fetch then`

```
function loadFile(src) {
  fetch(src)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => document.getElementById("displayText").innerText = data);
}
```

Note that you'll need to create an element with `id="displayText"` or something like this:

```
<p id="displayText">Loading...</p>
```